# Get all tables/views names that are used in A view in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on a python script where i am using teradata module.For example on executing:

*Show VIEW 331Agreement;*

I get view schema as output which is..

```
SelECT
Trade.Column1 as col1
FROM
D1_PPR.PP_TRADE TRADE
INNER JOIN
D1V_SST.dd_CUSTOMER cust
```

My requirement is i want to get list of all the tables/views which are there in inner join and from.. i.e.,

PP_TRADE TRADE
,dd_CUSTOMER

Is there any query in teradata by which i can fetch this information? Or maybe a table in which such information is stored?

Comment: `show select * from myview` will return all objects used in a view, one result set per table/view.

Comment: The query you mentioned will show schema of all the objects, but i want only name of those objects.

Comment: You would have to write code to parse the output, but that will quickly turn into a nightmare.

Comment: Extracting the name from a CREATE TABLE *xxx* or REPLACE VIEW *yyy* should be easy in Python. At least way easier than trying to extract from a Select (even without nested views). Btw, `show qualified select ...` will add the databasename to the REPLACE VIEW, too.